# Python PyQt and Psycopg2 with TableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, psycopg2, qtablewidget

Im trying to add data from a query to the table widget in pyqt but im having trouble getting it to put all the rows in. Right now my code only returns the first and third columns with data in them! Could really use some help in this!
there are a total of 5 columns and 7055 rows

My code:

```
import psycopg2
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def populate(self):
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=username host=servername password=passowrd")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM doarni.bins_v2""")
data = cur.fetchall()
a = len(data) #rows
b =  len(data[0]) #columns
self.ui.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(a)
self.ui.tableWidget.setColumnCount(b)
self.ui.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5'])
i = 1 #row
j = 0 #column
for j in range(a):
    for i in range(b):
        item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[j][i])
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(j, i, item)
self.ui.tableWidget.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code which also is configured to show Unicode strings:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows))
qs=QtCore.QString()
r=0
for row in rows:
    r=r+1
    col= 0
    for itm in row:
        if type(itm)==type('a'):
           item = qs.fromUtf8(itm, size=-1)
           qs=QtCore.QString()
        else:
            item = str(itm)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(r, col, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item))
        col = col+1
```